# Cross Tab Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count differen values as score. The values I want to count are 7 to 10. There are 1 to 6 also in the table but I don't want to count them. I can't get it right.

Values in table look like this:

```
RPO    RSP     RSV  
10     9       9
9      10      8 
10     7       7
7      10      8
4      4       3
```

I want the result look like this:

```
Score  RPO RSP RSV
10     2   2   0
9      1   1   1
7      1   1   1
```

Here is my code. Need to improve it.

```
select  

count(rank.rpo) as RPO,
count(rank.rsp) as RSP,
count(rank.rsv) as RSV

from
round 
left join base 
on round.id = base.round_id 

left join rank 
on round.id = rank.round_id and rank.number = base.number

where 
base.result = 1 
and round.round_date between '2013-03-15' and '2013-03-22'
and round.gameform = 'V4'
and round.gameform not like "OSPEC"

group by ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
drop table if exists ids;

create table ids (score int unsigned primary key)
select distinct rpo as score from rank
union
select distinct rsp as score from rank
union
select distinct rsv as score from rank;

select ids.score,
       sum(if(rank.rpo=ids.score,1,0)) as RPO,
       sum(if(rank.rsp=ids.score,1,0)) as RSP,
       sum(if(rank.rsv=ids.score,1,0)) as RSV
  from ids,round 
left join base on round.id = base.round_id 
left join rank on round.id = rank.round_id and rank.number = base.number
 where base.result = 1 
   and round.round_date between '2013-03-15' and '2013-03-22'
   and round.gameform = 'V4'
   and round.gameform not like "OSPEC"
   group by ids.score with rollup;
```

If you don't want to create a temp table, you could try:

```
select ids.score,
       sum(if(rank.rpo=ids.score,1,0)) as RPO,
       sum(if(rank.rsp=ids.score,1,0)) as RSP,
       sum(if(rank.rsv=ids.score,1,0)) as RSV
  from 
  (
      select distinct rpo as score from rank
      union
      select distinct rsp as score from rank
      union
      select distinct rsv as score from rank
  ) ids, round 
left join base on round.id = base.round_id 
left join rank on round.id = rank.round_id and rank.number = base.number
 where base.result = 1 
   and round.round_date between '2013-03-15' and '2013-03-22'
   and round.gameform = 'V4'
   and round.gameform not like "OSPEC"
group by ids.score with rollup;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b7d7/6 for a working example.

Comment: Can I do this without create table?

Comment: Yes, see second part of answer

Comment: Ross Smith II if you have time left please look at my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623494/convert-decimal-value-to-top-10